# Windows Phone 7: SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm trying to get Community.Csharp working with Windows Phone, I've tried using both the version from http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/ and compiling the main trunk with the WINDOWS_PHONE flag, but when I run the application on the phone I get an error when trying to execute any queries (but not when opening the database; only on queries): "Unable to open database file"

```
_conn = new SqliteConnection("Version=3,uri=file:recipes.sqlite");
_conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM recipes";
SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Interestingly though, I'm using the following to check for the existence of a table and no exceptions are thrown:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='" + tableName + "'";
SqliteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
exists = rdr.Read();
rdr.Close();
```

I have a Windows app which uses SQLite, so if I could use SQLite as opposed to Sterling DB or something else, that would save huge amounts of time. The problem I'm having currently is that once I open the database and close it, I cannot re-open it.

Comment: With over 100 questions you should know how to format your posts by now, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using the same library for our company's application and as far as I know, also documented at [http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com (under Some Recommendations )](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/), if you close the connection you'll need to recreate it again.

== ADDITIONAL COMMENTS ==

I've tracked down the cause of the error, created a fix and am testing it in our application. Briefly, in order to port the Community.CSharpSqlite library to WP7, the author wrote a FileStream wrapper around WP7 IsolatedStorageFileStream. When a db is opened, the db file stream is opened and read and closed by CSharpSqlite. But a handle to this stream is also stored in a Dictionary mapping the file path to stream. When a db is opened for a second time, the handle to the stream is retrieved but since it's closed (I'm assuming, haven't verified yet) the db fails to open.

I will attempt to get my changes deployed to the wp7sqlite.codeplex.com project, but in the meantime if you have the [source code](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/61252) make the following changes to Community.CsharpSqlite.FileStream

change from

```
    public FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, int unused)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream handler = null;
        if (FileStream.HandleTracker.TryGetValue(path, out handler))
        {
            _internal = handler;
        }
        else
        {
            if (mode == FileMode.Create || mode == FileMode.CreateNew)
            {
                _internal = IsolatedStorageIO.Default.CreateFile(path);
            }
            else
            {
                _internal = IsolatedStorageIO.Default.OpenFile(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            }
            FileStream.HandleTracker.Add(path, _internal);
        }
    }
```

to

```
    public FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, int unused)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream handler = null;
        if(FileStream.HandleTracker.TryGetValue(path, out handler)) 
        {
            _internal = handler;
            if(!_internal.CanRead) 
            {
                FileStream.HandleTracker.Remove(path);
                CreateOpenNewFile(path, mode);
            }
        } else {
            CreateOpenNewFile(path, mode);
        }
    }

    private void CreateOpenNewFile(string path, FileMode mode) 
    {
        if(mode == FileMode.Create || mode == FileMode.CreateNew) 
        {
            _internal = IsolatedStorageIO.Default.CreateFile(path);
        } else {
            try {
                _internal = IsolatedStorageIO.Default.OpenFile(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                var v = ex;
            }
        }
        FileStream.HandleTracker.Add(path, _internal);
    }
```

This is the first time I'm attempting to debug and contribute to an open source project. Any comments or thoughts on these changes will be greatly appreciated.

Alasdair.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix the problem. The source for the project seems very C-like in it's naming conventions.

Comment: Great job; +1! I'm preliminarily opting for @VanSiner's solution and hoping that your code gets included soon. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hi I have encountered the same issue ... I think i got the fix for it.
This is what I've done.

```
  public void CloseDB()
  {
    Connection.Close();               //Connection is a property(of type SqliteConnection) of my object
    FileStream.HandleTracker.Clear(); //This here is the fix
  }
```

I don't really need to change the dll.
I'm not yet sure if this will cause errors later on , but for now it works for me.
... I'm only a junior programmer:D

Comment: Seems to work (if you only have one connection open at a time, at least). If anyone else is stumped by `FileStream` not having the `HandleTracker` property, that's because this is not `System.IO.FileStream`, but `Community.CsharpSqlite.FileStream`.