# Intermittent Sqlite errors on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sqlite

I'm creating a database-driven app for WP7 using Sqlite. I've downloaded and compiled the libraries from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) and [Codeplex](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/) but have the same issues with both.

At seemingly random times during execution, I'll get "SQL logic error or missing database", "disk I/O error" or "no such table." Most times this occurs on SELECT statements, occassionally on an UPDATE, less on an INSERT. Sometimes the queries execute without problems, and other times the same queries throw these errors.

I already have an existing app on the marketplace using Sqlite that runs with no issues; most of the code, as well as the Community.CsharpSqlite DLLs, were copied from that project.

The database was created in [Sqlit Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) and added to the project as a resource, same as the existing, functioning app. Queries that fail in debug mode run fine in Sqlite Administrator. I've also recreated the blank database from scratch on the off-chance it was corrupt, but same random errors.

I've searched for resolutions, but ultimately keep coming to the same forum threads. I've run `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF`, verified the [compilation symbols](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/wiki/CompilerOptions), [tweaked the FileStream.HandleTracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594661/windows-phone-7-sqlite), and who knows what else at this point.

I suspected it might be my use of a background thread for populating the UI, but not only is the existing app working fine with threads, when I moved the code out of the background thread and into the UI thread, the errors still occurred.

I'm fairly certain the issue is with the database file itself, but I'm at my wits end as to what else to be looking for.

Comment: does this patch fix it? http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/issues/detail?id=172

Comment: I missed that one while looking through the issues. I've applied the patch and so far so good, but I'll need to test more. If all goes well and you add as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Though I'm still curious why my other project, which uses the older Codeplex version of the WP7 Sqlite library, works without issue.

Comment: That is interesting, I started with the codeplex version but it seemed the one on google code was more up to date.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not going to update the existing app since everything's working, but will continute with the Google Code version going forward.